# change array object boolean in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to angular and am trying to figure out why this wont work. I have an array of objects and within these objects there are keys and their values:

```
$scope.groups = [
        {
          title: 'Meal 1',
          content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1',
          show: false
        },
        {
          title: 'Meal 2',
          content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2',
          show: false
        }];
```

I have created a method that I want to loop over the array and change the 'show' boolean values to true. This is the body of this method:

```
for(var x = 0 ; x < 2; x++){
            $scope.groups[x].show = true;
        }
```

however it doesn't seem to work, and can't seem to understand why!. I am very new to angular so excuse my naivety with it all.

Could someone show me how to fix this?

Comment: Looks fine to me...where do you call that loop?

Comment: Its called when the user clicks a button - the idea is that the fucntion will loop through making all show values to true and therefore display the ng-show divs to the user

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Put a log statement to verify the method is being called.

Comment: Okay so it turns out, the loop is doing as it should do. However my issue is with the ng-show. This is the div: ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-show="{{group.show}}". After clicking the button that changes all show values to true it should then show all the group objects, however it doesnt

Comment: Ahh, there's the problem, ditch the `{{}}` in `ng-show` - I posted a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngShow` is an Angular directive - you do not need the `{{}}` when passing conditions:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-show="group.show">
```